# Keyboard Shortcuts on the Wallpaper

Tags: shortcut-keys, desktop-background

When one presses and holds the Super key, all of the shortcuts appear. Brilliant.

Is there a way to have this "image" set to wall paper ?

Cheerio.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install `gnome-screenshot` if it's not installed already by running

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-screenshot
   ```
2. Launch `gnome-screenshot` in an interactive mode by

   ```
   gnome-screenshot --interactive
   ```

   A pop-up window should appear.
3. Select "grab the whole screen" and "grab after a delay of 5 seconds" and then "Take screenshot".
4. Press and hold <kbd>super</kbd> so that the keyboard shortcuts list appears. Wait till the screenshot is taken.
5. Set the captured screenshot (crop first if needed using gThumb or GIMP) as your background image.

Comment: 6. ????
7. PROFIT!!!

Comment: @posmky   Removed my comment, I tried that just now - didn't work.